# Moving Left bar Block UP!

Tags: magento-1.9, xml

I have just added a static block into the left bar but am sturggling to move it to a certain position! If I want to move it to the top I assumed you leave sibling blank and put after as 0.

```
<default>
   <reference name="left">
      <block type="cms/block" name="tester" >
          <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>tester</block_id>
            <siblingName></siblingName>
            <after>0</after>
          </action>
      </block>
   </reference>
</default>
```

The block just sits at the bottom of the left bar and I cant get it to move!

Can someone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `before="-"` to show on top

```
<default>
   <reference name="left">
      <block type="cms/block" name="tester" before="-" >
          <!--
              The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
              You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
          -->
          <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>tester</block_id>
            <siblingName></siblingName>
            <after>0</after>
          </action>
      </block>
 </reference>
```

after that `clear your cache` or remove folder `var/cache`

Comment: That worked thanks! How about if I want to position above a static block with the identifier "recentposts" ?

Comment: `before="recentposts"` or `after="recentposts" `  recentposts must be block name..

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: Yep no problem had to wait the 10 mins before I could so sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1):

To move it to the top do this:

```
<default>
   <reference name="left">
      <block type="cms/block" name="tester" before="-">
          <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>tester</block_id>
          </action>
      </block>
  </reference>
</default>
```

If you want to move it after a certain block do this

```
<default>
   <reference name="left">
      <block type="cms/block" name="tester" after="block name here">
          <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>tester</block_id>
          </action>
      </block>
  </reference>
</default>
```